# How to convert a String with dates to DateTime? Flutter/Dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart, datetime

I have a string with 4 dates inside

```
I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 13:08
I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 12:54
I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 11:46
I/flutter (27269): 2022-07-13 12:42
```

i want to convert it to DateTime, i tried this DateTime.parse("myStringName"); but it stores only the last date.

Comment: Edit your question and give your exact 4 dates string

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: parse each date string separately.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
void main(){
  const myString='I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 13:08 I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 12:54 I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 11:46 I/flutter (27269): 2022-07-13 12:42';

  final myStrings=myString.split('I/flutter (27269): ')..removeAt(0);

  for(final dateString in myStrings){
    var myDateString=dateString.replaceAll('-', '').trim();
    print(DateTime.parse(myDateString));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const String firstDate = '2012-02-27 13:27'; 
const String secondDate = '2002-02-27 14:05';

final date1 = DateTime.tryParse(firstDate);
print(date1);

final date2 = DateTime.tryParse(secondDate);
print(date2);
```

Output:

> 2012-02-27 13:27:00.000

> 2002-02-27 14:05:00.000